# How do I override context for new OBJ Importer? (bpy.ops.wm.obj_import)

Tags: python, rendering, obj

I'm trying to import an OBJ file while rendering an animation, during the `frame_change_pre` event. The purpose is to [stream a sequence](https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ/wiki#streaming) of meshes into Blender, one at a time just before each render. I've successfully done this in Blender 3.6 and earlier using the Legacy OBJ importer (`bpy.ops.importer_scene.obj()`), but I'm running into problems with Blender 4.0 and the new OBJ importer (`bpy.ops.wm.obj_import()`). I keep getting the error:

`RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.wm.obj_import.poll() failed, context is incorrect`

Looking at the Blender source code ([source/blender/editors/io/io_obj.cc#L488](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/9c0bffcc89f174f160805de042b00ae7c201c40b/source/blender/editors/io/io_obj.cc#L488)), I've found that the poll function is the `WM_operator_winactive` function. [This function](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/9c0bffcc89f174f160805de042b00ae7c201c40b/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_operators.cc#L1253), as far as I can tell, simply checks for an active window, but correct me if I'm wrong.

I've tried using the `bpy.context.temp_override()` function with no success. I'm not sure how to override the context. How can I override the context for this specific case? Or what workarounds might exist?

Comment: There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here work for or have any association with the Blender Foundation. Since that addon is now written in C++ which we can't help with here, rather than python, I'd suggest you ask in a Blender developer forum, maybe at https://blender.chat/home .

Comment: @JohnEason I don't see why that means I can't ask the question here.

Comment: I didn't say that you couldn't just that you're more likely to get an answer in a developer forum.